# Deny access to Sharepoint for some O365 User

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to forbid user access to sharepoint and to give him access to other Office365 applications.User has Office E3 licence.

I removed user from Sharepoint collection https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

Removed from SPO site

```
Remove-SPOUser -Site "https://company.sharepoint.com/" -LoginName "user@company.com"
```

But user can still login to https://company.sharepoint.com/

```
Get-SPOUser -Site "https://company.sharepoint.com/" -LoginName "test@company.com"

Display Name Login Name                     Groups User Type
------------ ----------                     ------ ---------
test test test@company.com                  {}      Member
```

Used the site Cog --> Site Settings
On this new page click on Site Permissions
In the ribbon checked the user's name in the Check Permissions tool.

On site i want to remove access from,on site permissions, Site visitors are "Everyone except external users"

Here are permissions:

EditGiven through the "Members" group.

Limited AccessGiven through the "SharePointHome OrgLinks Viewers" group.

On site i want to remove access from,on site permissions, Site visitors are "Everyone except external users"

I located both groups,"SharePointHome OrgLinks Viewers" and "Members" and both have only one member: Everyone except external users

Is it safe to remove that group from site ?

Comment: Go to this page https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/groups.aspx and make sure NT auth or All Users(Windows) not added here. you will see all the groups which have permission

Comment: What will happen if i click "Delete User from Site Collection" for those 2 groups ?.I don't want to screw things up

Comment: User will be removed from that group. Just try with one user. BTW it is root site, all users need read access to it

Comment: In those 2 groups, there are no individual users in that group.